# Undefined reference error while using custom system call

Tags: c, kernel, system-calls

I'm trying to import new system call in the kernel 3.19. I've followed the tutorial given [here](https://tssurya.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/adding-a-hello-world-system-call-to-linux-kernel-3-16-0/)!

This is my simple code to implement factorial calculation via system call.

```
 #include <linux/kernel.h>


 asmlinkage long sys_fact(int a)
 {
    int n;
    int c;
    for(n = 1;n <= a;n++)
    c = c * n;  
    printk(KERN_INFO "Factorial calculated!\n");


    return((long) c);
 }
```

I'm getting Undefined reference to sys_fact error when I try to compile the C code.
The program in which I'm using this system call is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  int n;
  printf("Enter a number to calculate it's factorial\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Factorial of %d = %d\n", n, sys_fact(9));

  return 0;
}
```

My system is 64 bit ubuntu 14.04 and I've followed above mentioned tutorial according to my system.

Also, I've combined following commands while installing kernel, and I think this is the reason it did not gave error while installation of kernel.

```
 make && make modules_install && make install
```

Kernel installation took 2-3 hours, and I'm frustrated now.
Please help!!

Edits I made to syscall_64.tbl(final four entries).

```
 320    common  kexec_file_load     sys_kexec_file_load
 321    common  bpf                 sys_bpf
 322    64      execveat            stub_execveat
 323    common  fact                sys_fact
```

Comment: Show the changes you have done to `linux-3.8/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl`

Comment: @SantoshA updated my question. Have a look.

Comment: Refer this `http://linuxseekernel.blogspot.in/2014/07/adding-system-call-in-x86-qemu.html`

Answer (score 2):

The cause is that although you may be running with a new kernel, the #include headers and the C library are still old so they don't know anything about your newly added system call. So you cannot expect sys_fact to be defined.

As suggested by @SantoshA, the site http://linuxseekernel.blogspot.in/2014/07/adding-system-call-in-x86-qemu.html suggests using the syscall() function with the system call number.

Comment: syscall(323,n) returns 0 for any value of n (323 is system call number ofmy system call).

Answer (score 1):

your new `syscall` doesn't have a libc api, try invoke it with `syscall(323, args ...)` like shown in the tutorial.

And just checking that you have booted with your new kernel? You can follow the installation steps [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel). Or it might be easier to use an emulator like Qemu so you don't have to reboot.